# How to exclude a certain number of entries when calling upon a json feed

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

Here's a simple script that displays two latest posts under a certain label (in this example, the label "main"), in some section of a Blogger blog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function mainposts(json) {
  var item="";
  for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
   var mainContent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
   item += '<div>' + mainContent + '</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById("HTML7").innerHTML = item;
 }
</script>

<script src="http://www.MYBLOG.com/feeds/posts/default/-/main?max-results=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=mainposts"></script>
```

Note that `HMTL7` is the id that has been automatically assigned by Blogger to my HTML/Javascript-widget, which constitutes a `div` element by itself.

I have intentionally skipped including any post title variable in the script, so I'm just displaying the posts' content - no more, no less.

What I'd like to do is have two of these scripts for two different sections of my blog, where the second one would omit the two latest posts under the "main" label (same for both scripts), since they are already displayed by means of the first script.

What would I have to add to the second script to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `start-index` query parameter in the script src and initialize it from 3 (as the 1st and 2nd post would already be shown via the first instance of the code in the other section. The new code will look like -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function mainposts(json) {
    var item="";
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      var mainContent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
      item += '<div>' + mainContent + '</div>';
    }
    document.getElementById("HTML99").innerHTML = item;
  }
</script>

<script src="http://www.MYBLOG.com/feeds/posts/default/-/main?start-index=3&max-results=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=mainposts"></script>
```

The exact ID of HTML widget will depend on your blog (mainly it will be different from HTML7)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize for loop variable with 2 `var i = 2;` and maximum results 4 `max-results=4`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function mainposts(json) {
  var item="";
  for (var i = 2; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
   var mainContent = json.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
   item += '<div>' + mainContent + '</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById("HTML7").innerHTML = item;
 }
</script>

<script src="http://www.MYBLOG.com/feeds/posts/default/-/main?max-results=4&alt=json-in-script&callback=mainposts"></script>
```